# Update state in Child

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm very confused. I tried out this tutorial https://material-ui.com/components/radio-buttons/#radiogroup. But every time I clicked on a radio-button it didn't fill.

I checked in the handleFunctions if the state will be set. And yes, it set the new state correctly. So I don't know where my code is incorrect.

Thanks for all answers

Here is my code:

https://codepen.io/Y4roc/pen/MWjLWqz

```js
class Registration extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handlePackage = this.handlePackage.bind(this);
        this.nextStep = this.nextStep.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            form: {
                package: 0
            },
            step: 0
        };
    }

    handlePackage(event) {
        this.setState({form: {package: event.target.value}})
    }

    nextStep() {
        this.setState((state) => {
            return {step: state.step++};
        })
    }

    render() {
        const steps = [
            'Package',
            'Account',
            'Invoice Address',
            'Frist Steps'
        ];


        return <AuthenticationForm lg={6} md={8} sm={10}><Grid item>
            <Typography component="h1" variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                Registration
            </Typography>
        </Grid>
            <Grid item>
                <form>
                    <Stepper alternativeLabel activeStep={this.state.step}>
                        {steps.map((label) => (
                            <Step key={label}>
                                <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
                            </Step>
                        ))}
                    </Stepper>
                    {(this.state.step == 0) ? (<Grid container direction={"column"} spacing={2}>
                        <Grid item>
                            <FormControl component="fieldset">
                                <FormLabel component="legend">Choose your package</FormLabel>
                                <RadioGroup name={"package"} value={this.state.form.package} onChange={this.handlePackage}>
                                    <FormControlLabel value={1} control={<Radio/>} label={"Demo"}/>
                                    <FormControlLabel value={2} control={<Radio/>} label={"Bronze"} disabled/>
                                    <FormControlLabel value={3} control={<Radio/>} label={"Silber"} disabled/>
                                    <FormControlLabel value={4} control={<Radio/>} label={"Gold"} disabled/>
                                </RadioGroup>
                            </FormControl>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                            <Button variant={"contained"} color={"primary"} onClick={this.nextStep}>
                                Next
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>) : null}
                </form>
            </Grid>
        </AuthenticationForm>;
    }
}
```

The AuthenticationForm element is a wrapper to design the dialog box for this section of my app.

```js
class AuthenticationForm extends Component {
    render() {
        const {classes, lg, md, sm, children} = this.props

        return <Grid container spacing={0} justify="center" alignItems="center" direction="row"
                     className={classes.root}>
            <Grid item lg={lg} md={md} sm={sm}>
                <Grid container direction="column" justify="center" spacing={2}>
                    <Paper variant={"elevation"} className={classes.paper}>
                        {children}
                    </Paper>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>;
    }
}
```

Comment: why you did use `this.forceUpdate()` ?? already render happened when you updating the state !

Comment: It was a test. I forget to remove it, before I copy the code.

Comment: can you make this in codesandbox ? ill help you solve the problem.

Comment: I add the link to code pen (https://codepen.io/Y4roc/pen/MWjLWqz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `handlePackage` to this:

```
handlePackage(event) {
    this.setState({form: { package: Number(event.target.value)}});
}
```

and Radio group to this:

```
<RadioGroup name="package" value={this.state.form.package} onChange={this.handlePackage}>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your new state object does not match the initial state, it's missing the `package` property.

The `onClick` event returns a `value` of type string.

```js
const { FormControl, RadioGroup, FormControlLabel, Radio } = MaterialUI

class Registration extends React.Component {
  state = { form: { package: '1' }, step: 0 };

  handlePackage = (event) => {
    this.setState({ form: { package: event.target.value } });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <FormControl component="fieldset">
        <RadioGroup
          name={"package"}
          value={this.state.form.package}
          onChange={this.handlePackage}
        >
          <FormControlLabel value={"1"} control={<Radio />} label={"Demo"} />
          <FormControlLabel value={"2"} control={<Radio />} label={"Bronze"} />
          <FormControlLabel value={"3"} control={<Radio />} label={"Silber"} />
          <FormControlLabel value={"4"} control={<Radio />} label={"Gold"} />
        </RadioGroup>
      </FormControl>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Registration />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@latest/babel.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I updated my code in codepen. It doesn't work. Can you take a look on it?

Comment: click on "Run code snippet". It does work.

Comment: just make your intial state string `state = { form: { package: '1' }, step: 0 };`

Comment: Yeah, but look at my example in code pen. This didn't work. I updated it with your solution.

Comment: and also update the `value` prop of `FormControlLabel`. Alternatively you can convert to type number in your `onClick` handler.

Comment: I repeat, the `onClick` event returns a value of type string. I kindly ask you to look at the code for a minute before answering with multiple "this doesn't work"

Comment: Ah thanks! I thought react will return a number if I set the value of the component to a number. I'm starting with react and came from vue-js. There can you bind a value like it is.

Answer (score -1):

I think change this

```js
        this.state = {
            form: {
                package: 0
            },
            step: 0
        };
```

to

```js
        this.state = {
            form: 1,
            step: 0
        };
```

may work.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the soltuion.

Comment: @thhan it really a solution. In your question, the value is `this.state.form`, so I think package is useless. If you edit your code according me, it will work. You did not say you want the value to be `this.state.form.package`.

Comment: The problem was, that the event returns a string not a number.